# Why can't I use javascript to change the visibility property to hidden

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using javascript, so that when a user presses a button, a div will appear/disappear by changing the visibility property of the div. It works when the div is hidden and I want it to appear. However, when I presses the button again, it does not become hidden as it should.

```js
document.getElementById("SmileyButton").addEventListener("click", getSmileys);

function getSmileys() {
  var button = document.getElementById("SmileyDiv").style.visibility = 'visible';
  // document.getElementById("SmileyDiv").style.visibility = 'visible';
  if (button.visibility == 'hidden') {
    button.visibility = 'visible'
  } else {
    button.visibility = 'hidden'
  }
}
```

```css
.enterPostBackground {
  background-color: gainsboro;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
}

#SmileyDiv {
  height: 80px;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: scroll;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<div id="SmileyDiv"></div>
<div class="enterPostBackground">
  <button class="test" id="SmileyButton" style="font-size: 30px;float:left; " type="button" onclick="getSmileys()">&#128515</button>
</div>
```

Comment: In the function, replace the first line with: `var buttonStyle = document.getElementById("SmileyDiv").style;`. Now use `buttonStyle` instead of `button` in the rest of the function and it should work.

Comment: `var button = document.getElementById("SmileyDiv").style.visibility = 'visible'` sets `visibility` to `'visible'`, and assigns `'visible'` to `button`…!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may solve your problem.

Changes I did,

1. I removed the `onclick` from the button. You don't need it as long as you have registered the `click` event in the JavaScript side.
2. I fixed your HTML as you had incorrect markup. _(You forgot to close the `<script>` tag, as well you forgot to close the second `div` tag.
3. I change the logic of your script to make it more performant.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <style>
          .enterPostBackground {
              background-color: gainsboro;
              width: 400px;
              height: 50px;
          }

          #SmileyDiv {
              height: 80px;
              width: 160px;
              background-color: grey;
              overflow: scroll;
              visibility: hidden;
          }

      </style>
</head>

<body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="SmileyDiv"></div>
    <div class="enterPostBackground">

        <button 
            class="test" 
            id="SmileyButton" 
            style="font-size: 30px;float:left;"
            type="button"
          >&#128515</button>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
// I get the SmileyDiv here. This is because it runs only once, and makes 
// your script more performant.
var button = document.getElementById("SmileyDiv");
document.getElementById("SmileyButton").addEventListener("click", getSmileys);

// I set the initial visibility status here
button.style.visibility = 'visible';

function getSmileys() {
    // You had forgot to add the `.style` in the button property. That's 
    // why the button didn't worked properly.
    if (button.style.visibility === 'hidden') {
        button.style.visibility = 'visible'
    } else {
        button.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: @Natasha Drost if you are happy with what I provided you don't forget to mark my answer as the right one by clicking the checkmark :) Thanks in advance !! :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems there.

- You're assigning the result of `document.getElementById("SmileyDiv").style.visibility = 'visible';` to `button`. The result of an assignment expression is the value that was assigned, so `button` will be `"visible"`.
- Then you're trying to use a `visibility` property on `button`, but strings don't have that property. You probably meant to assign the result of `document.getElementById("SmileyDiv")` to `button`, but even then, you'd need `button.style.visibility`, not just `button.visibility`.
- The `style` property only reflects the element's *directly-assigned style information*, not anything applied to it by CSS. Your `div` doesn't have `visibility: xxx` in its `style` attribute, it *inherits* it via CSS. You need to use `getComputedStyle` to get the computed style of the `div`.
- You're using `addEventListener` **and** an `onclick`, so your function is getting called twice. Just use `addEventListener`.
- `button` is an odd variable name for a `div`. :-)

See comments:

```js
document.getElementById("SmileyButton").addEventListener("click", getSmileys);

function getSmileys() {
  // It's a div, not a button
  var div = document.getElementById("SmileyDiv");
  // ** Get the *computed* style of the div
  var style = getComputedStyle(div);
  if (style.visibility !== 'hidden') {
    div.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  } else {
    div.style.visibility = 'visible'
  }
}
```

```css
.enterPostBackground {
  background-color: gainsboro;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
}

#SmileyDiv {
  height: 80px;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: scroll;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<div id="SmileyDiv"></div>
<div class="enterPostBackground">
  <button class="test" id="SmileyButton" style="font-size: 30px;float:left; " type="button">&#128515</button>
</div>
```

Comment: OT: Always have to think of [this guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antony_Crowther) when reading your name.

Comment: @UweKeim - I didn't know the name! Wow, born a year and a half and 170 miles apart. And unsurprisingly, "Crowther" and "Crowder" are the same name, just different spellings, both deriving from Welsh "crwth" (aka the "Welsh harp" used by travelling minstrels).

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for `button.visibility`. Your button does not have a visibility attribute. You should check for `button.style.visibility`. You are also assigning the click listener twice, once in JS and the other in your HTML. This would cause the hide/show process to be reversed everytime.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("SmileyButton");
button.addEventListener("click", getSmileys);

function getSmileys() {
  var smileyDiv = document.getElementById("SmileyDiv");
  if(smileyDiv.style.visibility == 'hidden') {
    smileyDiv.style.visibility = 'visible'
  } else {
    smileyDiv.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  }
}
```

```css
.enterPostBackground {
  background-color: gainsboro;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
}

#SmileyDiv {
  height: 80px;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<div id="SmileyDiv"></div>
<div class="enterPostBackground">
  <button class="test" id="SmileyButton" style="font-size: 30px;float:left;visibility:hidden" type="button">&#128515</button>
</div>
```